# Alter disabled trigger in SQL Server without enabling it

Tags: sql-server, trigger

It seems like triggers get enabled automatically after altering them. How can I alter triggers programmatically without changing their enabled/disabled status?

Code to reproduce:

```
create trigger trig
on MyTable
after insert
as select 0

go

disable trigger trig on MyTable

go

select is_disabled from sys.triggers where name = 'trig'

go

alter trigger trig
on MyTable
after insert
as select 1

go

select is_disabled from sys.triggers where name = 'trig'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. You just need to disable it again. There is no [`ALTER TRIGGER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176072.aspx) syntax that prevents this.

The [disable trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748.aspx) topic explicitly calls out that

> Changing the trigger by using the ALTER TRIGGER statement enables the
>   trigger.